# How to arbitrarily change an associative array element's position?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time, with various solutions including `array_combine()`, `array_keys()`, `array_values()`, etc. but none of my solutions end up working properly.

Basically say we have an associative array in a *particular* order, and I'm trying to change it's position - either relatively or in an absolute manner, it doesn't matter.  This code demonstrates my buggy, inefficient version:

```
<?php

 $testArray = [
     'a' => 'Item 1',
     'b' => 'Item 2',
     'c' => 'Item 3',
     'd' => 'Item 4',
     'e' => 'Item 5',
     'f' => 'Item 6',
     'g' => 'Item 7',
     'h' => 'Item 8',
     'i' => 'Item 9',
 ];

 function moveKey($array, $key, $position) {
     // Now the array will have [position] => key
     $arrayKeyPos = array_keys($array);

     // This is so we can have duplicate positions and not overwrite one another
     // We're now [key] => position
     $arrayKeyPos = array_flip($arrayKeyPos);

     // Now this should change the key's position
     $arrayKeyPos[$key] = $position;

     // Sort them
     asort($arrayKeyPos, SORT_NUMERIC);

     // At this point the array's keys are in correct order.  But there
     // is no easy way to attach the values?  This is pretty ugly:

     $newArray = [];
     foreach($arrayKeyPos as $k => $v) {
         $newArray[$k] = $array[$k];
     }

     return $newArray;
 }

 $testArray = moveKey($testArray, 'c', 99);
 // This "sort of" works, it moves it to the 4th, not 3rd, position:
 $testArray = moveKey($testArray, 'h', 3);
```

So to be clear, my question is how do I accomplish the above but have the 2nd call always actually move it to that Nth position?

Obviously if the index is out of range (-99, 99 etc on an array smaller than that) it should just go to the top/bottom, but for those such as '3', '5', etc this code fails miserably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moves the element specified by `$key` to the end of the array if `$position` is greater than the last position in the array and moves it to the beginning if it is less than 1:

```
function moveKey($array, $key, $position) {

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $vals = array_values($array);

    $pos  = array_search($key, $keys);

    $new_key = array_splice($keys, $pos, 1);
    $new_val = array_splice($vals, $pos, 1);    

    array_splice($keys, $position-1, 0, $new_key);
    array_splice($vals, $position-1, 0, $new_val);    

    return array_combine($keys, $vals);        
}
```

- Create numerically indexed arrays for keys and values
- Find numeric position of key
- Extract the found key and value arrays from keys and values arrays
- Splice them into keys and values arrays at the new position
- Combine new keys and values arrays into an associative array

To just return the array when the `$position` is out of bounds:

```
function moveKey($array, $key, $position, $wrap=true) {

    if($wrap === false && ($position < 1 || $position > count($array)) {
        return $array;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: This is perfect with the only side-effect that a very small number (say -99) will actually wrap around backwards.  An obvious easy fix, `if($position < 1) $position = 1;`...

Comment: -99 moves it to the beginning and 99 moves to the end, that's what I thought you requested?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `unset` to remove the key/value from its original position, and use `slice` in combination with `+` to insert that pair at the desired absolute position:

```
function moveKey($array, $key, $position) {
    $value = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    return  array_slice($array, 0, $position, true) +
            [$key => $value] +
            array_slice($array, $position, null, true);
}
```

The given position is interpreted as zero-based, so the following:

```
var_export (moveKey($testArray, "h", 3));
```

will return:

```
array (
  'a' => 'Item 1',
  'b' => 'Item 2',
  'c' => 'Item 3',
  'h' => 'Item 8',
  'd' => 'Item 4',
  'e' => 'Item 5',
  'f' => 'Item 6',
  'g' => 'Item 7',
  'i' => 'Item 9',
)
```

If the position argument is greater than the highest index, the key/value pair will end up in the array's last position.

If the position argument is negative the position is counted backwards from the end of the array. If that leads to a position before the start of the array, the pair will end up at the start of the returned array.

#### Why zero-based

In PHP indexed arrays are zero-based. For instance, if you take `array_values($array)`, the first element will have index `0`. Or if you create an indexed array like `[1, 2, 3]`, the value `1` will be at index `0`. So, if you are going to mix 1-based and 0-based index numbers, you'll get into a lot of `-1` and `+1` code, which in the end will be more confusing than helpful. I would strongly suggest to adapt to the 0-based index numbers.

#### Why counting from the end when negative

In PHP several functions provide this feature, i.e. where a negative argument for a position is interpreted as a backward offset from the end of the array. For instance [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

> If offset is positive then the start of removed portion is at that offset from the beginning of the input array. If offset is negative then it starts that far from the end of the input array.

The same goes for [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), and several string functions like [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [`strspn`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php). A similar treatment of negative values is implemented for the limit argument to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Therefore I think it is better to stick with this behaviour and see it as a feature. Of course, as mentioned in comments, it is easy to disable this feature and transform any negative offset to `0` with `if ($position < 0) $position = 0;`.

Comment: Same as above - with negative numbers, this will wrap around backwards.  The obvious fix being if($position < 0) $position = 0; .. I did a benchmark between this and @AbraCadaver's answer, and your's is actually 2x as fast over 100k iterations.  The only other difference is this is 0-based (0 is the beginning, 1 is the 2nd element) while AbraCadaver's is 1-based.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I have added some notes about why I would stick with zero-based offsets and interpreting negative offsets as counting from the end of the array. I would not call this something to *fix*. It is a common feature. :-)